# How to fit an image in the menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit my image in the menu's first `a` tag. Basically what I want is  the image to exactly fit in the menu's first `a` tag without showing any padding.  I'm new to html and css. The output of the code can be viewed at

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_topnav

Code:

```css
                    .menu {
                              margin: 0;
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }


                    .topnav {
                              overflow: hidden;
                              background-color: #D4D4D4;
                    }


                    .topnav a {
                              float: left;
                              color: black;
                              text-align: center;
                              padding: 14px 16px;
                              text-decoration: none;
                              font-size: 17px;
                    }


                    .topnav a:hover {
                              background-color: #6F8CFE;
                              color: #EEEEEE;
                    }


                    .topnav a.active {
                              background-color: #4CAF50;
                              color: white;
                    }
```

```html
<body>

<div class ="menu">

        <div class="topnav">
                  <a class ="active" href="#home"><img src ="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" height="15" width="30"/></a>
                  <a href="#news">News</a>
                  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                  <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-left:16px">
                  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
                  <p>Some content..</p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the image as `background-image` then gave the `a` tag a `width` to fit the image in without padding.

Also the image is not an `png` so you wont see the background color on the `a` tag.

Here is my code:

```css
.menu {
                              margin: 0;
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }


                    .topnav {
                              overflow: hidden;
                              background-color: #D4D4D4;
                    }


                    .topnav a {
                              float: left;
                              color: black;
                              text-align: center;
                              padding: 14px 16px;
                              text-decoration: none;
                              font-size: 17px;
                    }


                    .topnav a:hover {
                              background-color: #6F8CFE;
                              color: #EEEEEE;
                    }


                    .topnav a.active {
                              background-color: #4CAF50;
                              color: white;
                    }
                    
                    
                   .topnav a:first-child {
                        background-image: url(http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif);
                        background-size: cover;
                        background-repeat: no-repeat;
                        width: 48px;
                    }
```

```html
<body>

<div class ="menu">

        <div class="topnav">
                  <a class ="active" href="#home">&nbsp;</a>
                  <a href="#news">News</a>
                  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                  <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-left:16px">
                  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
                  <p>Some content..</p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```css
.menu {
                              margin: 0;
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }


                    .topnav {
                              overflow: hidden;
                              background-color: #D4D4D4;
                    }


                    .topnav a {
                              float: left;
                              color: black;
                              text-align: center;
                              padding: 14px 16px;
                              text-decoration: none;
                              font-size: 17px;
                    }


                    .topnav a:hover {
                              background-color: #6F8CFE;
                              color: #EEEEEE;
                    }


                    .topnav a.active {
                              background-color: #4CAF50;
                              color: white;
                    }
                    
                    .topnav a:first-child {
                      padding: 0px;
                    }
                    .topnav a img {
                      display: block;
    max-width: 100%;

                    }
```

```html
<div class ="menu">

                    <div class="topnav">

                              <a class ="active" href="#home"><img src ="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" height="48"/></a>

                              <a href="#news">News</a>

                              <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

                              <a href="#about">About</a>

                    </div>


                    <div style="padding-left:16px">

                              <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>

                              <p>Some content..</p>

                    </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu {
                              margin: 0;
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }


                    .topnav {
                              overflow: hidden;
                              background-color: #D4D4D4;
                    }


                    .topnav a {
                              float: left;
                              color: black;
                              text-align: center;
                              padding: 14px 16px;
                              text-decoration: none;
                              font-size: 17px;
                    }


                    .topnav a:hover {
                              background-color: #6F8CFE;
                              color: #EEEEEE;
                    }


                    .active {
                              background-color: #ffffff;
                    }
```

```html
<body>

<div class ="menu">

        <div class="topnav">
                 <a class ="active" href="#home" style="padding:0;"><img src ="http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif" style="width:62px;" /></a>
                  <a href="#news">News</a>
                  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                  <a href="#about">About</a>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-left:16px">
                  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
                  <p>Some content..</p>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
```